# Defining route in laravel corrctly

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem like this

```
 <a href="{{route('essayanswers.show',[$essayAnswers]) }}" >
```

I have define route for this in web.php , like this.

```
Route::resource('essayanswers', 'EssayAnswerController');

EssayAnswer {#541 ▼
  #fillable: array:4 [▼
    0 => "user_id"
    1 => "essay_id"
    2 => "essay"
    3 => "content"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

But when I use dd command inside the EssayAnswerController I Got a input like this.I canno't acces the attributes of essayAnswer

How to define route for this in web.php file in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) as per documentation

```
Route::resource('essayanswers', 'EssayAnswerController', ['parameters' => [
    'show' => 'essayAnswer'
]]);
```